# Из двоичного дерева в матричное

Tags: дерево, бинарное-дерево, алгоритм, c++

Здравствуйте! Есть у меня двоичное дерево (допустим, с четными ключами, соответственно четная половина). Как из него собрать матричное (четное матричное поддерево, условимся на этом)? Под четным матричным поддеревом будет иметься в виду следующее: ключи в дереве только четные, при добавлении ключа выполняются свойства обычного матричного дерева, добавляются паразитические, чтобы существовал путь от созданной вершины до корня дерева.

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы не создавать новое дерево, а в существующем добавить паразитические, чтобы выполнялось необходимое условие?

Comment: может, вы объясните, что означает «с чётными ключами»? и что означает «матричное поддерево»?

Comment: С четными ключами - это значит фигурируют только четные ключи
Матричное дерево состоит из четного и нечетного. В моей ситуации можно рассматривать только четное, с нечетным ровно такие же действия.

Вот например функция, которая находит предка для ключа N:


    int f(int N) {
        int AL = 1, BL = N;
        while (!(BL % 2)) {
            BL /= 2;
            AL *= 2;
        }
        return AL * 2 * (1 + 2 * (BL / 4));
    }



Допустим, для 2 и 6 - это 4, для 4 и 12 - это 8, для 10 и 14 - это 12 и так далее..

Comment: Так вот, когда добавляешь 2, а потом, к примеру, 10, то неизбежно появление паразитических ключей: 4 и 12, а также общего корня: 8. Так вот, при переходе от матричного дерева к двоичному, мы просто исключаем эти паразитические ключи, и перенаправляем указатели от их предков на добавленные ключи.

Comment: Простите, ничего не понял. Ваше понятие «бинарного дерева» имеет что-то общее со структурой данных, которая рекурсивно определяется как «пустое дерево либо пара из левого и правого бинарных поддеревьев»? Потому что мне сложно понять, какое отношение ваш код имеет к этой структуре данных.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что функция `f` заменяет два самых правых ненулевых бита на `10`?

Comment: Бинарное, оно же двоичное дерево, обычное его понятие.

У матричного дерева я рассматриваю только ее четную часть, то есть там ключи состоят только из четных натуральных чисел. Полное дерево высоты 2: 2<-4->6, 3: (2<-4->6)<-8->(10<-12->14) и так далее. Ну в общем, если мою мысль не поняли, то забудьте, сам подумаю. Вообще это задача не нужна на практике, чисто теоретическая, для понимаю, считаю ее бесполезной, да и оно хуже многих деревьев, что уж тут говорить..

Comment: Вот [определение](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE). Там не говорится ничего ни о том, что данные в узлах (их вы называете «ключами», да?) являются числами, ни тем более о том, что данные у родительского и дочернего узлов должны быть как-то связаны. У вас же какая-то неизвестная обычным программистам структура данных, которую вы называете деревом. (Поэтому и ответов пока не много.)

Comment: Между прочим, весьма интересно. Я раньше о matrix tree (или правильнее называть на русском???) и не слышал.

--

Похоже, что [матричное дерево](http://www.tadviser.ru/index.php/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8:%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) это новая структура данных:


    Матричное дерево - структура поиска данных, самобалансирующееся двоичное дерево с удвоенной скоростью поиска


Видимо автор -     Васильев А.Е. (лично мне неизвестен).

--

По крайней мере поиск *"matrix tree"* удовлетворительных результатов не дает.

Comment: @beraliv, Вы в комментарии пишете, что матричное дерево хуже, а вот автор утверждает, что лучше:

    во всех случаях рекомендованного использования самобалансирующихся двоичных деревьев поиска, за исключением деревьев, элементы которых содержат ключи, отсортированные в возрастающей/убывающей последовательности вида 2n. 

Правда, я для себя так и не понял, может  ли эта структура эффективно работать с ключами, отличными от чисел.

Comment: @beralix, вот нашел  [код матричного дерева](http://code.google.com/p/matrixtree/source/browse/trunk/matrixtree.py).

Что-то большие сомнения в справедливости утверждений автора о применимости его творения возникли у меня.

IMHO "паразитные" узлы всю картину портят. 

--

Непосредственно по поводу Вашего вопроса. Почему построение нового матричного дерева Вас смущает?

Ведь если структура узла Вашего двоичного и строящегося матричного деревьев совпадает, то достаточно в процессе обхода своего дерева исключать из него узлы и тут же вставлять их в матричное (конечно выбросив там создание узла).

Comment: Ну создать новое - думаю не проблема, интересно, препод примет такие рассуждения, посмотрим, экзамен покажет :)